# How I can speed up the compilation of a document with multiple images?

Tags: graphics, compiling

When I compile a large document with many images, this compilation is very slow. Exist any method that allow read ONLY (no rendering) the width and height of imagen and then simulate this image with a dummy rule. For example:

```
\newdimen\onlyWidth
\newdimen\onlyHeight

\setlenght{\onlyWidth}{\readOnlyWidth{\path\of\image.jpg}}  
\setlenght{\onlyHeight}{\readOnlyHeight{\path\of\image.jpg}}  

\begin{figure}[t]
    \rule{\onlyWidth}{\onlyHeight}
    \caption{any}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

still reads the files to determine size info but just typesets a rule.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `\includegraphics` you can try to use the `[draft]` option in this way `\includegraphics[draft]{image.jpg}`. This will improve the time of compilation but I don't know if it is sufficient.

Or you can use something like this

```
\usepackage{calc}
\def\mygraphic{\includegraphics{...}}

\newlength\imageheight
\setlength\imageheight{\heightof{\mygraphic}}

\mygraphic % to insert the image

\vspace{\graphicheight} % a blank space of the height of your image
```

Comment: The vspace won't make the same space as the graphic as it is a vertical mode command  whereas `\includegraphics` is a horizontal mode thing so would start a paragraph and get `\parskip` or `\baselineskip` spacing in addition to its natural height. You could use `\rule` instead of `\vspace` but that is the same (but less efficient) as using `draft`.