# Speed up the compilation of a document with a lot of tikzpictures made with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, compiling

I have a document with a lot of `tikzpicture` made with `pgfplots`, most of them take data from files so the compilation may be very long. In order to have only a draft I would like to have blank images with same dimension of the full ones.

Until now I used a trick of having a `tikzpicture` with an empty `axis` environment of the same dimensions of the original one and with some `if` statements I included the blank or the full image like this:

```
\newcommand{\img}{Y} % immages Y(es) or N(o)
...
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\img}{Y}}{%
    \input{Immagini/full.tex}}{%
    \input{Immagini/empty.tex}}
  \caption{caption}
\end{figure}
```

file `full.tex`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[height=9cm, width=.8\textwidth]
    \addplot table [x index=0, y index=2] {dati.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

file `empty.tex`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[height=9cm, width=.8\textwidth]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But today I read this question [How I can speed up the compilation of a document with multiple images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121540/how-i-can-speed-up-the-compilation-of-a-document-with-multiple-images) and now I would like to know if there is a similar way to the `draft` option of the package `graphicx` that does the same thing with `tikzpicture`.

Comment: There are a few related questions about this on the site e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111566/how-to-turn-off-an-environment-e-g-tikzpicture-for-faster-draft-compiling if you search for `tikzpicture draft` you can see more.

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you thought about using the `external` library, which compiles your `tikzpicture`s into external PDFs that then only have to be included in your final document?

Comment: @Jake Ok, with your suggestions I got the solution, can I answer to my own question?

Comment: @Red: Sure! You just have to wait a day (I think) before you can accept the answer, but you can (and should) post the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A part of the total solution is to use the `external` library as suggested and then put the option `draft` to `\documentclass[draft]{whatever}`. But doing so the image is replaced by a box of fixed dimensions, not equal to those of the real image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \input{anderlini_10.tex}
  \caption{caption of this beautiful image}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This happens because the external image created is not imported with `\includegraphics`, to correct this it is sufficient to add this line (`\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code=\includegraphics{#1}}`) before `\tikzexternalize`. In this way we obtain the desired result:

[image]